# how to comment a jquery code block which has a line with php code in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to comment a code block, but i have a line in my javascript block which has jquery and php both

like this

```
jq('.time_slot').each(function(index) {
    var a = jq(this).autocomplete({ 
        serviceUrl:"<? echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>business/information/add/autocomplete",
        params: { suggessions_id:28767 }, //aditional parameters
        onSelect:function(value,data){ jq(this).trigger('change');  } 
    });
});
```

with out this line

```
      serviceUrl:"<? echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>business/information/add/autocomplete",
```

i can comment this block using

```
/*

*/
```

but now i can not use it , also i tried with single line comments , like this

```
//jq('.time_slot').each(function(index) {
    //var a = jq(this).autocomplete({ 
        //serviceUrl:"<? echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>business/information/add/autocomplete",
       // params: { suggessions_id:28767 }, //aditional parameters
       // onSelect:function(value,data){ jq(this).trigger('change');  } 
   // });
   // });
```

but for this line

```
 serviceUrl:"<? echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>business/information/add/autocomplete",
```

it is not working .

so i ended up with a very odinary solution like this

```
 //serviceUrl:"
<? //echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>
//business/information/add/autocomplete",
```

what is the best way to comment my code block , thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, admittedly, this isn't pretty, but if you want to cancel out the commingled PHP and JavaScript in one fell swoop, you might consider wrapping the entire block in a PHP condition that always returns false, e.g:

```
<?php if (1 == 0) { ?>
jq('.time_slot').each(function(index) {
    var a = jq(this).autocomplete({ 
        serviceUrl:"<? echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>business/information/add/autocomplete",
        params: { suggessions_id:28767 }, //aditional parameters
        onSelect:function(value,data){ jq(this).trigger('change');  } 
    });
});
<?php } ?>
```

Ugly, I know, but undeniably quick and effective for big blocks of mixed code.

Answer (score 2):

On runtime, if your php configuration's short_open_tag is enabled, those script enclosed in `<? ?>` would have been parsed by php parser in the server before sending the html (that contains the said javascript with comment) to the browser.

So it should technically work if you use // to comment out that line, as the javascript parser won't be aware that the string was generated from php.

Make sure you have short_open_tag enabled or use `<?php` instead of short tags `(<?)`.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik theres no better solution that you provided. PHP and JS comments are always separate, you can put JS comment into PHP's echo function.

PHP parser will always try to run code between  blocks.

Imho best solution is to comment whole JS code using /* and */ and use single line comment to prevent PHP running  php code block.

Answer (score 0):

That is the best way already. Can't think of any better ways..